# Conversion of data format from a single object to an array of objects of key value pairs

Tags: javascript, json

I have a data in a single object as json-format:

```
var a = {
    "1": "alpha",
    "2": "beta",
    "3": "ceta"
}
```

I want to convert it into the following format:

```
var b = [
    {id: 1, label: "alpha"},
    {id: 2, label: "beta"},
    {id: 3, label: "ceta"}
];
```

Can someone suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try following

```js
var a = {
  "1": "alpha",
  "2": "beta",
  "3": "ceta"
}

var b = [];

for (var key in a) {
  if (a.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    b.push({
      "id": key,
      "label": a[key]
    });
  }
}

console.dir(b);
```

**Please note** - You need to update your object `a` - Commas are missing

Answer (score 5):

This proposal features [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/object/keys) and [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var a = { "1": "alpha", "2": "beta", "3": "ceta" },
    b = Object.keys(a).map(function (k) {
        return { id: k, label: a[k] };
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(b, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I meant to do this but then wrote something else entirely :D. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Nina - Nice answer!

Answer (score 4):

try

```
var b = [];

for ( var key in a )
{
   b.push( { id : key, label :a[key] } );
}
console.log(b);
```